# use alias name as parameter

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

how to i get alias name for my query. Below i am using spring boot with hibernate JPA native query. What i want is to get alias name **cbpartnerid** as WHERE parameter, because i get **c_b_partner** from 2 table with condition.

But spring giver me error this :

ERROR 2021-02-26 06:00:02.492 [http-nio-8080-exec-9] o.h.e.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions(142) - ERROR: column "cbpartnerid" does not exist

i hope can solve this issue without change overall query or modify backend code.

here are my native query :

````
(CASE
WHEN i.transaction = 'SALES' OR i.transaction = 'CUSTOMER_RETURN' THEN j.c_bpartner_id
WHEN i.transaction = 'INVENTORY_OUT' OR i.transaction = 'INVENTORY_OUT' THEN l.c_bpartner_id
ELSE null
END) AS **cbpartnerid**
FROM so_transaction i
LEFT JOIN so_orderline j ON j.so_orderline_id = i.so_orderline_id LEFT JOIN so_inventoryline k ON k.so_inventoryline_id = i.so_inventoryline_id
LEFT JOIN so_inventory l ON  l.so_inventory_id = k.so_inventory_id
GROUP BY i.created, i.transaction, i.m_product_id, i.productname, i.createdby, **cbpartnerid** ORDER BY i.m_product_id DESC ```
````

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution is a subquery.

Your code, reduced to the essential, looks like

```
SELECT /* complicated expression */ AS alias,
       /* other columns */
FROM atable
GROUP BY alias;
```

This can be rewritten to

```
SELECT alias, /* other columns */
FROM (SELECT /* complicated expression */ AS alias,
             /* other columns */
      FROM atable) AS subq
GROUP BY alias;
```

Comment: thanks @laurenz-albe for answers. I will check as soon as possible

Answer (score -1):

````
SELECT i.created, i.transaction, i.m_product_id, i.productname, i.createdby,
(CASE
WHEN i.transaction = 'SALES' OR i.transaction = 'CUSTOMER_RETURN' THEN j.c_bpartner_id
WHEN i.transaction = 'INVENTORY_OUT' OR i.transaction = 'INVENTORY_OUT' THEN l.c_bpartner_id
ELSE null
END) AS **cbpartnerid**
FROM so_transaction i
LEFT JOIN so_orderline j ON j.so_orderline_id = i.so_orderline_id LEFT JOIN so_inventoryline k ON k.so_inventoryline_id = i.so_inventoryline_id
LEFT JOIN so_inventory l ON  l.so_inventory_id = k.so_inventory_id
GROUP BY i.created, i.transaction, i.m_product_id, i.productname, i.createdby, **cbpartnerid** ORDER BY i.m_product_id DESC ```
````